# How can I pass a map result to $.ajax jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am retrieving values from html component as value-pair in jQuery.

```
var items = $('.bid').map(function () {
    return { "date": $(this).attr('date'), "Id": $(this).attr('qId') };
});
```

The output `items` gives me the following:

```
0: {date: "01/09/2018 10:55:39", Id: "1626"}
1: {date: "03/09/2018 10:55:39", Id: "1674"}
2: {date: "05/09/2018 22:55:39", Id: "1624"}
```

How can I pass the following to `$.ajax()` in jQuery ?

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Cars")',
  data: {
    dataObj: items
  },
  success: function (resp) {
    console.log('success');
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('error');
  }
});
```

Comment: The approach seems fine to me, except that you should set `contentType` to `json` for sending JSON data to server. What do you receive on the server, by the way?

Comment: Is it currently failing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: My issue is that the date is getting converted to `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. Its not preserving the date when I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

> JSON.stringify()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

in the javascript and decode it in the php with

> json_decode();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

also if you want to pass an array to client site again you can use,

> json_encode()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and echo it. and decode it in client site with

> JSON.parse()

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp